# PHP CloudFront Proxy / Forward Requests For Video Streams Via API

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, curl, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to forward a request made from the client for a stream, where it keeps the requests originally made from the video player intact:

```
Content-Type: Keep-Alive;
Range: 0-
...
```

---

**What I'm Using:**

- Frontend: Web - ReactJS
- Backend: PHP REST API
- CDN: AWS CloudFront
- Storage: AWS S3

---

**Architecture Graphic**

[image: Architecture]

---

**Reason:**

I need to be able to authenticate the user with our own JWT middleware through the REST to validate if they can access the file.

---

**Constraints:**

Cannot use `nginx` to forward the request, unless there is still a way to authenticate it with the PHP Middleware.

---

**What I've Looked Into:**

**`aws php sdk`**

I've look at the AWS PHP, but the documentation on this specific functionality seems to be missing.

**`guzzle` + `php curl`**

I'm afraid my knowledge is lacking in terms of what I would need to pass onto the CloudFront for this to work.

**`cloudfront signed url/signature`**

Unless I'm mistaken, this would not be helpful because the video expiration for access would be set by AWS and not by the App's REST API, so if they refresh their JWT it would not be updated with the signature.

**`why not s3 directly?`**

S3 doesn't support headers for chunks like, `Range: 0-100 bytes`.

---

Any help or recommendations would be appreciated, even if it means recommending to buy something pre-built to look at how they implemented it.

**======= UPDATE: June 29, 2020 =======**

After the recommendation from @ChrisWilliams, I ended up creating a script on AWS [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/) with the following configurations:

**Trigger:** CloudFront - `viewer request`

The reason for `viewer request` was because it's the only way to get the GET query parameters from the user's original request.

**Function Code:**

(Please forgive the very rough code to get things working)

**File:** `index.js`

```js
// IMPORTS
const zlib = require('zlib');
const https = require('https');

// HTML ERROR TEMPLATE
const content = `
<\!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Unauthorized Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Unauthorized!</p>
  </body>
</html>
`;

// TRIGGER FUNCTION
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    // Getting request and response
    const originalResponse = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

    // Setup for html page (cont content)
    const buffer = zlib.gzipSync(content); 
    const base64EncodedBody = buffer.toString('base64');
    
    // Response Templates
    var response401 = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': [{key:'Content-Type', value: 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}],
            'content-encoding' : [{key:'Content-Encoding', value: 'gzip'}]
         },
        body: base64EncodedBody,
        bodyEncoding: 'base64',
        status: '401',
        statusDescription: "OK"
     };
     
    var response500 = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': [{key:'Content-Type', value: 'text/html; charset=utf-8'}],
            'content-encoding' : [{key:'Content-Encoding', value: 'gzip'}]
         },
        body: base64EncodedBody,
        bodyEncoding: 'base64',
        status: '500',
        statusDescription: "OK"
     };
     
    // Perform Http Request
    const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      
        // Expected ?token=ey...
        const req = https.get(`https://myauthserver.com/?${(request && request.querystring) || ''}`, function(res) {
          if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
            return reject(response401);
          }

          return resolve({
            status: '200'
          });
        });
        
        req.on('error', (e) => {
          reject(response500);
        });
    }).catch(error => error);
    
    // Get results from promise
    const results = await response;
    if (results.status === '200') {
        // Successful request - continue with the rest of the process
        callback(null, request);  
    }

    // Not successful, show the errors results (401 or 500)
    callback(null, results);
};
```

**NOTE:** You will have to try this a few times in case any typos or syntax errors arise because of the caching. I also recommend trying this with different IP addresses to validate access to the content. Not to mention you will get scenarios of `502` if the returned request isn't formatted correctly with the `base64EncodedBody`.

**DOUBLE NOTE:** This was after looking at the tutorials from AWS that weren't working or outdated and looking at the comments of multiple devs not getting things working.

Comment: Why can you not use a Labda@Edge function to validate the JWT token?

Comment: How would that work? The Authentication Middleware is on separate server, so is there a special hook/middleware with CloudFront checking for authentication externally, and if so is it exclusively tied to Lambda?

Comment: You can have a Lambda@Edge function that would process the JWT header, either validating within the function itself or calling an external endpoint that you have to validate. If its invalid it would reject the request preventing it from getting forwarded. Heres an article Amazon published: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/authorizationedge-how-to-use-lambdaedge-and-json-web-tokens-to-enhance-web-application-security/

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this so far? Normally to solve this you'd just write some proxy-like PHP code that takes a request and converts it into an appropriate request after authenticating and then sending the converted request upstream and doing the same with the response (but the other way). There's a [PHP proxy](https://github.com/jenssegers/php-proxy) library that can act as a starting point or you can follow the AWS guideline on how to open seekable S3 streams [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-stream-wrapper.html).

Comment: @apokryfos I mentioned I tried, aws php ask, guzzle, cloudfront, and aws php sdk for s3. The PHP Proxy looks promising, I'll check that out. Thanks for that.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams That might also help if PHP Proxy doesn't work. In order of preference, proxy would be first, then cloudfront authentication with a custom domain associated to cloudfront.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a [Lambda@Edge](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/edge/) function rather than adding a third stage in front of your CloudFront.

By adding a proxy in front of your CloudFront it could lead to issues with debug, and allows someone to bypass the proxy to reach your CloudFront origin without locking it down.

Using a Lambda@Edge function guarantees that the solution validates the authenticity of the JWT token, it could be configured to either validate the JWT token with the Lambda function directly or have the Lambda call an endpoint you build to validate. If the JWT is invalid it can reject the request.

Amazon have a great [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/authorizationedge-how-to-use-lambdaedge-and-json-web-tokens-to-enhance-web-application-security/) with a demo stack that demonstrates how you can make use of this.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks. This was the right way to go. Although the caching with CloudFront and Lamda@Edge was a bit annoying and the fact that logging is stored in different Edge locations was pretty challenging, but I got it to work.